# R: Extract controlled vocabulary from character vector

Tags: r, extract, corpus, vocabulary

Suppose text data looks like this:

```
txt <- c("peter likes red", "mary likes green", "bob likes blue")
```

I want to reduce those string to words from this controlled vocabulary:

```
voc <- c("peter", "mary", "bob", "red", "green", "blue")
```

The result should be a vector:

```
c("peter red", "mary green", "bob blue")
```

One can use the `tm` library but that only gives me a dense document term matrix:

```
foo <- VCorpus(VectorSource(txt))
inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(foo, list(dictionary = voc)))
Non-/sparse entries: 6/12
Sparsity           : 67%
Maximal term length: 5
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

    Terms
Docs blue bob green mary peter red
   1    0   0     0    0     1   1
   2    0   0     1    1     0   0
   3    1   1     0    0     0   0
```

How can I get the vector solution with one string per vector element?

The solution should be fast. I'm also a big fan of base R.

**EDIT: Comparison of solutions so far**

On my data, James' solution is about four times faster than Sotos'. But it runs out of memory when I make the step from `length(text)` 1k to 10k. Sotos' solution still runs at 10k.

Given that my data has `length(txt)` ~1M and `length(voc)` ~5k I estimate that Sotos' solution will take 18 hours to finish, given that it does not run out of memory.

Isn't there anything faster?

Comment: Would a non regex approach suffice for your case? E.g. something like `sapply(strsplit(txt, " ", TRUE), function(x) paste(collapse = " ", x[x %in% voc]))`

Comment: @alexis_laz you win! Your solution finishes in 10 minutes instead of 18 hours. Would you like to create a dedicated answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 3):

A base only method is:

```
apply(sapply(paste0("\\b",voc,"\\b"), function(x) grepl(x,txt)), 1, function(x) paste(voc[x],collapse=" "))
[1] "peter red"  "mary green" "bob blue"
```

The `sapply` part recreates the membership matrix you used the tm package for, while the `apply` iterates over its rows to pull out the relevant terms from the vocabulary to paste together.

Comment: @Sotos I've fixed it to add word boundaries, so it should work now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
sapply(stri_extract_all_regex(txt, paste0('\\b', voc, collapse = '|', '\\b')), paste, collapse = ' ')
#[1] "peter red"  "mary green" "bob blue"
```

or full `stringi`

```
stri_paste_list(stri_extract_all_regex(txt, paste0('\\b', voc, collapse = '|', '\\b')), sep = ' ')
#[1] "peter red"  "mary green" "bob blue"
```

Comment: I'm checking your solutions. Note that the result of `txt <- c("peters like reds", "marys like greens", "bobs like blues")` should be empty.

Comment: What do you mean "It should be empty"?

Comment: I mean that your first solution should not extract `peter` from `peters`. In other words, `peters` is not in the controlled vocabulyry, `peter` is.

Comment: The problem with your first solution is that it produces the same output for `txt1 <- c("peter likes red", "mary likes green", "bob likes blue")` and for `txt2 <- c("peters like reds", "marys like greens", "bobs like blues")`. For `txt2` the result should be empty because no word is in the vocabulary. For your second solution I may have to update the `stringi` library cause the `stri_paste_list` function can't be found.

Comment: Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Ok check now. I added boundaries to get exact match so it should work

Comment: `stringi` is really fast actually from my experience